# wpf treeview Клавиша Минус сворачивает узел

Tags: wpf, treeview

У меня есть treeview с вложеними ветками, где в качестве контента используется UserControl с TextBox-ами. В TexBox пользователь должен поставить "+" или "-", textBox_PreviewKeyDown обрабатывает правильность.
Проблема в том, что принажатии Минус, сворачивается узел treeview, а мне это не нужно.
Как исправить?

```
private void x_TreeViev_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Subtract)
            { e.Handled = true;}
        }
```

не помогло,просто останавливает обработку, и минус не ставится в textbox.